# Moved Windows 7 partition, now it doesn't boot

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, bootloader, multi-boot

This is my current partition structure: [image: Partition structure]
(Full size version [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbZG7.jpg).)

Previously that green free space was on the left side of `L:`

I had XP first and then installed Windows 7 to `L:`.
So the `L:` is the `C:` of my Windows 7.

As I had low drive space and a drive can be extended only when there is free space on the right side, I used Paragon Partition Manager 11 Free Edition to move the partition and to bring the free space to the right side (also I selected sector by sector copy, instead of normal copy when moving the partition).

Now when I select Windows 7 in the boot menu it wont boot. It says boot device inaccessible.
I am able to work only on Windows XP.

I have EasyBCD and VistaBootPro, but don't know what to do with them to fix this problem.

Comment: I have to ask: _why_ do you have that many partitions on one disk? Is there really a good reason to separate Programs and Data for example?

Comment: Yes, much lesser defragmentation. As I keep adding/removing data like movies/tv shows etc. Also I like to keep my OS Drive separate from program files. I has worked for me over the years very well.

Comment: I used to do the same, but by spreading your files over several partitions on the same disk, in a way you're also fragmenting the free space and your data between them.

Comment: With Windows 7, your really not gaining much benefit. Windows 7 defragments daily by default and does an excellent job. In addition, partition activists are considered risky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I solved it myself.

Surprisingly I just created a new entry with name "Windows 7 Second" and the drive pointing to L: again. And it worked. Thanks :)

I really wanted to solve it without having to use the Win7 DVD and this did it.

Answer (score 1):

Moving your freespace doesn't necessarily change anything meaningful as far as your hard drive partition is concerned.

The main problem is probably that Win7 is no longer in what it recognizes to be the L drive and therefore cannot "find" itself.

Try renaming the partition for Win7 to L drive again. If this does not work, boot from a Win7 disk and do a repair install.